# How can I keep logcat connected with my phone after a phone restart?

Tags: android

I am testing my app, and a part of this app is after the phone restarts, a `BroadcastReceiver` is supposed to know this, and do some stuff. But this `BroadcastReceiver` does not display any data, so I want to see some information with `LogCat`. Every time I restart my phone, the phone disconnects from android studio and I cannot see any more `LogCat`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try to use Toast along with Log.d(). This will give you a popup on the screen and you don't need to depend on logcat output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also test BOOT_COMPLETED without completely restarting the phone. The logcat connection will drop momentarily, but will come right back up.

In a terminal window, execute:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p com.example.package
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need AndroidStudio in order to see Logcat's output: just use `adb logcat -d > logfile` command instead (you can read about `adb logcat` command [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)).

Said that, there is short period of time after phone restart when `Log.d` (and other log commands) won't log anything. You could bump into this issue if your app registers for `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, or you build home screen replacement, etc. In such cases you could create your own logger which writes log messages into a file, and just read this file after phone startup completed.